# Implicit declaration of function with structs

Tags: c, struct, implicit-declaration

I am trying to fix my last implicit declaration of a function by creating the prototype function in my header file. The lab is to write structs and currently I have my Main.c, RandomNums.h, and RandomNums.c. My function in RandomNums.c is finished but I'm not sure how I should write it in RandomNums.h

Below is what I have for my RandomNums.c file and the issue is that setRandomVals is an implicit declaration in Main.c

```
struct RandomNums setRandomVals(int low,int high) {
    struct RandomNums r;
    r.var1= (rand() % (high -low + 1)) + low;
    r.var2= (rand() % (high -low + 1)) + low;
    r.var3= (rand() % (high -low + 1)) + low;
     
    return r;
}
```

Below is how I called SetRandomVals

```
RandomNums r = SetRandomVals(low, high);
```

The prototype I had tried was

```
setRandomVals(int low,int high);
```

As for my professor, I may not edit the Main.c file.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype shall be the same as the function header in the definition: `struct RandomNums setRandomVals(int low,int high)`.

and it should be declared before any caller calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

The return type needs to be included in the declaration.

And to do that, you will need to include the struct definition in the `.h`.

```c
struct RandomNums { ... };

struct RandomNums setRandomVals(int low, int high);
```

By the way, you can avoid using the word `struct` everywhere by using a (possibly-anonymous) struct.

```c
typedef struct { ... } RandomNums;

RandomNums setRandomVals(int low, int high);
```

Comment: Some people do not agree on that last point; [Linux kernel coding standards](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs) say `typedef struct` is almost always a mistake, while C++ thinks it's okay.

Comment: @Neil, Re "*Some people do not agree on that last point*", No, they don't. One can use `typedef` to avoid using `struct` everywhere, and that's not debatable. But they apparently disagree about it being a good idea. I'm definitely against typedeffing pointers, but someone seeing a problem with `RandomNums` being a struct type baffles my mind.

Comment: @Neil It's subjective and Linux is among a minority of code bases in the world insisting on that style. Apart from style concerns, the Linux kernel coding standard is otherwise a joke - an amateur-level document. And then we can look at the Linux kernel source itself. And the conclusion will be that it's pretty much the last place on Earth where one should go searching for canonical references of how to write proper C...

Comment: Fair enough. However, unlike `C++`, one should be, at least aware, that one is exporting an addition to the `typedef`-namespace, which is different from the tag-namespace.

Comment: @Neil, That's a fancy way of saying the name is `foo` instead of `struct foo`. And I would hope so. That's the entire point.